# Open source or free web site customers data solution

Tags: open-source

I'm really not sure if that's the right place to ask it , but I'm so used to this site so i'll just give it a try.

I'm interviewing many people for a certion mission, and i'm looking for a an easy way to organize the people according to some properties (age, origin , hobbies, education etc'...).
I need a website which will allow me to insert new people using the properties I want to add, and in addition will allow me to sort or filter on different fields. (for example will show me only people above the age of 24).
It would be great if I'd be able to add a combo box, In addition to regular fields with a bunch of options lilke failed/passed/undecided and then filter based on that either.

I need a web based solution , cause I'm not the only person who will look throught the data and add/delete content.

Is there anything similar to that I can use ?

Thanks alot !!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would [Highrise](http://highrisehq.com/) suit your needs? They offer a free plan for up to 250 contacts. I'm not too familiar with it, but the [API](http://developer.37signals.com/highrise/) might do what you need.

Comment: Seems like it's 30-day free trial , I need something completely free.

Comment: There is a completely free version available, but it's limited to 2 users and 250 contacts. There's a small link on the pricing page. Just do a CTRL+F. Good luck!

Comment: I might try sugarcrm , cause this free version is pretty limited.